# Pivot by count in postgres or sql-server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, t-sql

I have 2 sample tables, i need months group on rows and columns

rows group by #tnx table and columns month group by #act
and values filled with count(tnx_no)

```
 create table #tnx(tnx_id int,tnx_date int,tnx_no)
    insert into #tnx values(1,200140101,1),(1,200140101,2),(2,20130901,2),(2,20130802,2)

create table #act(act_id int,act_dt int)
insert into #act values(1,20140101),(1,20130809),(2,20140101),(2,20140203)
```

--i need this output sample output.

```
/*
                                            -- the values are count(tnx_no)

                    0-6 monthns      0          1           2           3
months from #tnx    7-12 months     12          34          32          54
                    13-18 months    12          09          89          07  
                    18+ months      11          100         190         190


                                    0-6 months 7-12 months 13-18 months  >18months

                                    --months from #act


    /*
```

The client app is in postgres,and sql server appreciate any help

Comment: not clear in your output explain clearly how you can get 100,190

Comment: @Sathish i think OP is putting sample output? he needs something as above?

Comment: @user can you add some more data to reflect your `sample output`